# Liquibase support for Postgres and Oracle

Tags: database, oracle, postgresql, liquibase

This question is related to Liquibase.

Our application code base has to support Oracle and Postgres. One product is on Oracle and other is on Postgres. However there are changesets that are common to both products. Is there any tool that can help execute liquibase changesets that are database agnostic and tweak them based on the target database?

If more information is needed or if I am unclear I will elaborate.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this is possible, but it can be tedious. One of your key tools is to use the `dbms` attribute on your changesets - this marks a particular changeset as being only applicable to a certain dbms. This is useful for things where you have to use platform-specific SQL, such as in stored procedures and functions. Another key technique is using properties (Liquibase calls them changelog parameters) to do things like vary the data type used on a column depending on the dbms. Search for '[Liquibase changelog parameters](https://www.google.com/search?q=Liquibase%20changelog%20parameters&oq=Liquibase%20changelog%20parameters)' for documentation on this.

As you run into problems, feel free to post new questions here on StackOverflow - there is a large community of users and developers that can help. It will help if your questions are focused to a single issue at a time and include:

1. This is what I did (full command, changelog, etc.)
2. This is what I expected to happen (expected output from command, state of the database)
3. This is what actually happened (actual full output from command, stack traces, state of the database)